# Populate virtual SQLite FTS5 (full text search) table from content table

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts5

I've followed https://kimsereylam.com/sqlite/2020/03/06/full-text-search-with-sqlite.html to set up [SQLite's virtual table extension FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) for full text search on an [external content table](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#external_content_and_contentless_tables).
While the blog shows how to set up triggers to keep the virtual FTS table updated with the data:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    short_description TEXT
)

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE user_fts USING fts5(
    username, 
    short_description, 
    email UNINDEXED, 
    content='user', 
    content_rowid='id' 
)

CREATE TRIGGER user_ai AFTER INSERT ON user
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO user_fts (rowid, username, short_description)
        VALUES (new.id, new.username, new.short_description);
    END;
...
```

I am failing to populate the FTS table from all previous data in an analogous fashion.
I'll stick to the example from the blog:

```
INSERT INTO user_fts (rowid, username, short_description) SELECT (id, username, short_description) FROM user;
```

However, sqlite (3.37.2) fails with `row value misused`.

Please explain how `id`, `content_rowid`, `rowid` and `new.id` are related and how to modify the query to update the FTS table properly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there is https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - what should I do with this Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO user_fts (rowid, username, short_description) SELECT id, username, short_description FROM user;
```

(no parentheses) works.

`rowid` is a unique 64 bit unsigned integer row id.
If the table contains an integer primary key (as `id` in `user`), they are the same (alias). I.e. user.rowid == user.id = user_fts.rowid.
Doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

The `new` refers to the element being inserted.
Doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

`content_rowid` links the virtual FTS table to the external data table  row id column (it defaults to rowid).
Doc: https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#external_content_tables